# Sacar un vector de impares de una matriz. Python

Tags: python, array

```
n = int(raw_input("Ingrese N\n"))
cont = 0
matriz = []
for i in range(n):
     matriz.append([0]*n)
       for i in range(n):
         for j in range(n): 
            matriz[i][j] = int(raw_input("Elemento %d, %d : " % (i,j)))
              if(matriz[i][j] / 2 != 0):
                 vector[cont] = matriz[i][j]
                 cont = cont + 1
  print matriz
```

Tengo que sacar de la matriz los valores impares e imprimirlos en un vector.
como hago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
n = int(raw_input("Ingrese N\n"))
cont = 0
vector = []
matriz = [None]*n
for i in range(n):
    matriz[i] = [None]*n
    for j in range(n):
        matriz[i][j] = random.randint(0, 100) #Opcional para llenar el array con numeros aleatorios debes comentar la linea anterior para usar esta
        # matriz[i][j] = int(raw_input("Elemento %d, %d : " % (i,j)))


for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if(matriz[i][j] % 2 != 0):
            vector.append(matriz[i][j])
print vector
```

Comment: Espero te sirva esta solución.

Comment: Me saca error en el if(matriz[i][j] % 2 != 0):, dice
TypeError: 'int' object has no atribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Listo, ya corregì posibles erores, funcional en python 2.7

Comment: Listo muchas gracias

Comment: Una observación, no  deberías usar `range` + indexado para recorrer la matriz y obtener los impares, es mucho más pitónico y eficiente usar `for in`, por ejemplo mediante una lista por compresión sería: `vector = [n for fila in matriz for n in fila if n % 2]`.